# How to add multiple permission to user in django?

Tags: python, django, permissions

I want to add multiple permission for a user in single api request.
I have a array of permission code name, how to pass it in the view?
Is for loop is the only way? or any other ting will work?

```
u = User.objects.get(username="admin_user_1")
permission = Permission.objects.get(name="Can add user")
u.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

This code can be used for single permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a queryset of your permissions by checking if a field is present in a list - the list you can get through request.POST. You can then use `*` notation to expand the list into the m2m `add()` function:

```py
u = User.objects.get(username="admin_user_1")
permissions_list = request.POST.getlist('permissions') # this may be differ
permissions = Permission.objects.filter(name__in=permissions_list)
u.user_permissions.add(*permissions)
```